# Error in processing request 200 phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I keep on getting this error message
"error on processing request error code: 200  error text:OK"

when selecting from a database in phpmyadmin. I re-installed  and restarted the server and phpmyadmin but still facing same issue.

This is my log file of the error message

```
"pma_version": "4.3.7",
    "browser_name": "CHROME",
    "browser_version": "41.0.2272.101",
    "user_os": "Win",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36",
    "locale": "en",
    "configuration_storage": "enabled",
    "php_version": "5.6.3",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "onerror",
        "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier",
        "stack": [
            {
                "line": 390,
                "func": "?",
                "context": [
                    "  }",
                    "",
                    "  // SCROLLBARS",
                    "",
                    "  // Prepare DOM reads needed to update HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r",
                    "Date: Mon, 23 Mar 2015 15:04:46 GMT\r",
                    "Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3\r",
                    "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.3\r",
                    "Expires: Mon, 23 Mar 2015 16:04:46 GMT\r",
                    "Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r",
                    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r"
                ],
                "filename": "codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36",
        "name": "SyntaxError",
        "uri": "index.php?"
    },
    "script_name": "index.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "pages": [
            {
                "hash": "index.php?db=&table=&server=1&target=&token=814184a233707cc347e32deb678d6da0"
            }
        ],
        "current_index": "1"
    }
}
```

I am also facing some issues with Jquery and JavaScript which i believe is because of this error.

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.3.7 is a bit outdated; can you try with the current release (which at the moment is 4.3.12)?

Comment: I did try that as well I got the same error so i reverted to the version i had as a backup

Comment: Do you get this error while trying from another browser as well?

Comment: Related bug: [#4901 Error processing request](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpmyadmin/bugs/4901/).